# How to delete R.id

Tags: android

Experts,

For example, I have been once defined a R.id called age in xml, then I decided not to use it and deleted it.

Now, after I deleted it in xml, it seems it still exists in R.id, for I can still use below statement without warning/error.

This really bother me, I like to remove everything redundant, even a extra blank.
Plus, it would cause my program malfunction.

How to delete it?

Thanks.

```
  txtThird = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.age);
```

Comment: Did you read this ? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.id.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete not used ids from R, use clean function in your `Android Studio`.

Build -> Clean project
[image]

Answer (score 2):

FYI R file is an auto-generated file, contains automatically generated index of the resources. So if you delete any resources then it will be effected when you clean/build project.

### How it actually generates IDs?

When your application is compiled, *aapt* generates the R class, which contains resource IDs for all the resources in your res/ directory.

> **Caution**: You should never modify the R.java file by hand—it is
>   generated by the aapt tool when your project is compiled. Any changes
>   are overridden next time you compile.

Read more about accessing resources https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html

Comment: But it would cause careless error, for example, I created R.id.age, later I changed to R.id.xxx. But I can still use R.id.age(I mean, usually if I use something not exists, it becomes red color, but in this case, android studio didn't warn me)